# Apache Poi can't Open .docx

Tags: java, android, apache-poi, docx

I'm actually working on a mobile report filling application and I need it to open previous reports.

The code compile and I can write new file but when I tried to open an existing one I got the following error :

```
W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: http://xml.org/sax/properties/declaration-handler
W/System.err:     at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxLoader.<init>(Locale.java:3397)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$XmlReaderSaxLoader.<init>(Locale.java:3087)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.getSaxLoader(Locale.java:3072)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1272)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1259)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderBase.parse(SchemaTypeLoaderBase.java:345)
    at org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.DocumentDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown Source:6)
    at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.onDocumentRead(XWPFDocument.java:180)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:184)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.<init>(XWPFDocument.java:138)
    at com.example.testcreatedoc.MainActivity.readButton(MainActivity.java:81)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6935)
    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:12738)
W/System.err:     at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26211)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
W/System.err: Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: http://xml.org/sax/properties/declaration-handler
    at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.setProperty(ExpatReader.java:162)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxLoader.<init>(Locale.java:3391)
    ... 23 more
```

Here are the used libraries :

```
implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:4.1.2'
implementation 'javax.xml.stream:stax-api:1.0'

implementation group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.17'
implementation group: 'dom4j', name: 'dom4j', version: '1.6.1'
```

And how I try to open the file :

```
public void readButton(View view) {
    try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
        XWPFDocument xwpfDocument = new XWPFDocument(fileInputStream);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help and sorry for my poor english

Comment: Can you post the full Stack Trace?

Comment: As far as I know, the Apache POI uses JavaX packages which are not part of the Android SDK because of the 64K method limit of dex; so when you try to run certain versions of POI, they would give you unexpected exceptions - CNFE, UOE, etc. In my experiments, I struggled a lot to read certain doc formats. In the end, I had to send these files to remote server where it would be read and formatted by python scripts; to a format that my app's POI understands.

Comment: this sounds like https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XMLBEANS-542 -- are you using xmlbeans 4.0.0 which has this fix?